# How to publish an app only for iPhone and not to iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, appstore-approval

I know couple of similar questions are asked before. But they are outdated with the XCode versions, as the XCode now seems to provide different / better features.

I have developed a Flutter app for both Android and iOS. My app target is mobile users and not tab or iPad users.

When I am publishing my app to Apple App Store, I am being asked to submit iPad 3rd Gen and 2nd Gen screenshots.

The app works in iPad, but the layout is not great. Alignment issues and similar UI matters are there.

I'm on XCode 11, is there a way to avoid publishing to iPad? I saw a tick box to uncheck iPad in XCode, maybe unchecking this will save me?

If there is no way to protect from being published to iPad, can I provide the not so good layout screenshots for now? Will they pass the review? In this case I can fix the layouts in next release.

Comment: What does "no so good" mean exactly? Broken / unusable? Or just ugly?

Comment: @LouFranco Yes, ugly. Rest of the things should work, because as far as I know iPhone and iPad share the same Framework

Comment: You probably will not get rejected for ugly screenshots.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Xcode

1. Choose your project from the Project Navigator
2. Choose your app target
3. Choose the "General" tab
4. In the "Deployment Info" section, check only the iPhone device (uncheck iPad)

Comment: Appreciate your answer, will check. Then I have to again Archive, Validate, Distribute right? Also then in App Store, I don't have to upload IPad images?

Comment: Yes, you need a new IPA. The App Record can't know about it until you associate a build.  You can check with TestFlight to make sure you can't download on an iPad, and then see what happens (you could write a note to the reviewer or just upload your bad screenshots which won't matter)

Comment: OK. So that means I need a new build and maybe I will require the "ugly screenshots" which is not an issue. Right, will check. How about the build and version numbers? New ones needed? I already launched a one to Test flight, but never to real production.  As for a side question, what will happen if the app "breaks" in iPad somehow? (Considering that I have unchecked the iPad tickbox as well)

Comment: You always need a new build # for every build you submit to the appstore, but not a new marketing version until you release.

Comment: iPad may try to run the iPhone version of the app (at the phone size).  This is what happens to apps that don't support iPad and I don't think you can stop that (and I wouldn't worry about it)

Comment: You are awesome.! I will check this out and comment back.

Comment: Your answer worked! Thank you! Now my app is under review for release. And I did not have to upload iPad Images!

Comment: once more question. My app version is 1.0.1 and build number is 2. But in App Store, there is another place to "type" the app version, which I missed to update, it is there as 1.0. This number need to match with the exact app version number (1.0.1) ? Or else this is just a number which we want users to see? I guess this issue will not be a problem for the review?

Comment: I am in the same position. I haven't taken iPad screenshots but I can see it emulates an iPhone when I run it on the iPad simulator. Do I still need to take iPad screenshots or will my phone versions be enough?

Comment: NO, this is not true. It (apparently) has to continue supporting any users who installed it on an iPhone, so you're not allowed to change it!

Comment: Hi, my app was being testing on TextFlight and now I am removing the iPad support. I just wanna ask if it will effect my application review process in any context or not?

Comment: Just try it. The only people that can answer this for sure are Apple app reviewers. I think it will be fine

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode 12.4 Update**

Project -> App -> Deployment -> Targeted Device Families -> Select iPhone

Comment: Hi, my app was being testing on TextFlight and now I am removing the iPad support. I just wanna ask if it will effect my application review process in any context or not?

Comment: currently, iPad can run apps targeted to iPhones. In my experience, the applications are tested on an iPad and were rejected multiple times when UI wouldn't work appropriately. I would suggest testing it yourself on an iPad first before submitting it for review.

Comment: I did that... It works fine but they keep rejecting it claiming there is an issue with the app on iPad 16.3.1 ios version and xcode does not even provide support for this version to test it out.

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode 14 Update**

Project -> Target -> General -> Supported Destinations -> Remove iPad (and Mac)

Comment: Hi, my app was being testing on TextFlight and now I am removing the iPad support. I just wanna ask if it will effect my application review process in any context or not?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 14.2 Update

Project -> Runner -> Build Settings -> Deployment -> Remove iPad (and Mac)

[image: Flutter How to publish an app only for iPhone and not for iPad?]